# If צחק refers to the 3 worst misdeeds why Itzchak was called so?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, vayera, yitzchak

On the Posuk: "וַתֵּרֶא שָׂרָה אֶת־בֶּן־הָגָר הַמִּצְרִית אֲשֶׁר־יָלְדָה לְאַבְרָהָם מְצַחֵק׃" Rashi ([Gen 21.9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.21.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.21.9.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=he)) explains the meaning of the root צחק:

> **מצחק:** לְשׁוֹן **עֲ"זָ**, כְּמוֹ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר וַיָּקֻמוּ לְצַחֵק ,
>   דָּ"אַ לְשׁוֹן **גִּלּוּי עֲרָיוֹת**, כְּמָה דְּתֵימָא לְצַחֶק בִּי,
>   דָּ"אַ לְשׁוֹן **רְצִיחָה**, כְּמוֹ יָקוּמוּ נָא הַנְּעָרִים וִישַׂחֲקוּ לְפָנֵינוּ וְגוֹ'
>
> This means **worshipping idols**,
>   ... Another explanation is that it refers to **immoral conduct**,
>   ...Another explanation is that it refers to a murder

If that's the meaning of the root, how our forefather could be named Itzchak?

Answer (score 3):

The name יצחק means *he will rejoice*, meaning that this will be shown to be good. The term used for Yishmael, מצחק, means that he mocked actively and viciously. It therefore is a completely different usage.

Rav Hirsch explains that their are two different meanings involved. [Vayeirah 21:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8216/showrashi/true#v3)

> 3 And Abraham named his son who had been born to him, whom Sarah had
>   borne to him, Isaac.
>
> the birth of this child was צחק, something, according to natural
>   conditions, rather laughable (see above on [Chapter XVII,
>   17](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8212/showrashi/true#v17)).
>   So when Abraham called his son יצחק these facts were vividly in his
>   mind.

The statement in Vayeira 17:17 shows:

> 17 And Abraham fell on his face and **rejoiced**, and he said to himself,
>   "Will [a child] be born to one who is a hundred years old, and will
>   Sarah, who is ninety years old, give birth?"

On the other hand, Yishmael actually went to great extremes in his *making fun* of the ideas of Avraham. As Rav Hirsch says on [Vayeira 21:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8216/showrashi/true#v9):

> He took in just as much of the great ideas of Abraham to make him
>   ironically disdain them, and over that which the world in general
>   greeted merely with צחוק, in which (V.6) derision was only lightly
>   mixed, Ishmael was completely מְצַחֵק, and was therefore completely
>   unfit to join with Isaac in the heritage of Abraham.

Comment: this is a great explanation. But I don't understand why would the Torah use the same language for all? Why not the other way around - Ishmael rejoiced and Avraham did something sinful?

Comment: @alberko It doesn't use the same language for all.  One is kal one is piel

Comment: Agreed, and how does Piel turn joy into murder?

Comment: @AlBerko No the piel tyrns the kal action into a forceful action.

Answer (score -1):

And I say: (Rabbi Shimon ben Yochai) 
“God forbid that there be, in the house of this righteous man, anyone doing such things! Rather, this “playing around” has to do with the inheritance - Ishmael was fooling around and saying, “I am the eldest, and so I will take a double portion.”
https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Sotah.6?lang=bi

in this context, perhaps one can say that Ishmael was doing more than just playing around. He was, more precisely, “Isaac-ing.”  In other words, he was trying to be Isaac - to take his place, to be the inheritor.

Comment: Interesting! Is it your own idea, or whose?

Comment: I understand, but how mimicking Itzhak results in 3 deadly sins? And a double portion of what exactly?

Comment: Considering the op based his question off the opinion that misachek meant the three sins, I don't think we can answer the question by bringing the opinion that it does not mean the three sins.